# Extract xml sub-string from a string in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a log file which contains multiple lines of logs. Some of these lines have an xml string. My aim is to parse each line and convert the xml substring present in the log text to a POJO (using JAXB) in case xml is present.

Currently, I am using String.indexOf(tag) to extract substring from the original string, where tag is the first xml tag that will occur in the original string, and is equal to the base class of the POJO.

Please suggest some way to do this.

Much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I know of no XML parser where you can say "start parsing XML here and stop when you get to the end of the document". All parsers that I know of will report an error if there is anything beyond the end of the document, which means that if XML is nested inside some larger text, you have the difficult challenge of locating the end of the document before invoking the parser.

However, if you use a SAX parser, then you can count nested start and end tags, and abort the parse when the final end tag is notified. If you implement your application as a SAX filter, then it can pass everything it's given to the JAXB process, suppressing the error that would otherwise arise because of the unwanted content that follows the XML.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the SAX route. Will check it out. Meanwhile, I will try and generify my current solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this wont work if there is some random text in front of the desired xml right?

Comment: Your question suggested that you knew how to get rid of the text that precedes the XML you're interested in. I was concerned with the more difficult problem of finding the end of the XML.

Comment: Yes I can remove using position of first xml tag using string manipulation, but I guess a better solution would be to suppress the SAXParseException "Content is not allowed in prolog" so that i dont have to do the extra step of string trimming.

Comment: It would be a good solution if it worked. But XML parsers don't continue after an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to wrap the whole log line in `<log>....</log>` tags and parse the result. Of course it will fail if there are special characters such as `<` or `&` outside the XML part -- but then it's hard to find any solution that will handle that. Using an error-repairing parser like TagSoup might help.